# setExactAndAllowWhileIdle is almost triggered exactly

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I searched the Internet for an answer but have not found anything.
I wrote an app where every 17 minute an SMS must be sent ( every 17 minute means: 10:17:00 and not at 10:17:49 )
Therefore, I use an AlarmManager with setExactAndAllowWhileIdle, and AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP.

```
Long whenToFireOff = treeMapInstance.getFirstEntryInTreeMap().getKey();

Calendar alarmCal = Calendar.getInstance();
alarmCal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, treeMapInstance.convertMillisecondsToHour(whenToFireOff));
alarmCal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, treeMapInstance.convertMillisecondsToMinutes(whenToFireOff));

am.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmCal.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
```

However, it gets always triggered round about 10:17:49, and the next scheduled alarm also at 10:34:49, and so on.

I calculated my next alarm correctly. I am absolutely 100% sure :)

Is setExactAndAllowWhileIdle not as exactly as it is written in the documentation?

Thanks

Comment: Strange, have you tried calling it with a shorter interval, only a few seconds, to see whether the calculations are off by the same 49 seconds then?

Comment: I can try that but I think there is some limitation, 9 minutes but I will try that.

Comment: I know that the limit is mentioned in the docs - but I haven't encountered it on two phones. On Android 9, it runs every 5s, for more than 24hrs. On Android 10 had to whitelist to let it run more than 1hr - but then it also runs every 5s for more than 24hr.